# Is it possible to clear registry of OrderRepository?

Tags: magento2, php, repositories

I have a mass action which saves hundreds of orders via OrderRepository. 
And sometimes the process fails with **PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of XXX bytes exhausted**

Because `save()` method of class `OrderRepository` adds order to array `$registry`. And garbage collector cann't destroy these objects because there are links on them.

```js
public function save(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $entity)
{
    //Some code

    $this->registry[$entity->getEntityId()] = $entity;
    return $this->registry[$entity->getEntityId()];
}
```

So, I want to flush the registry or free up memory in Magento way.

*PS I know `$order->save();` is workaround. It gets much less memory than `OrderRepository->save()` But it is deprecated.

Comment: As a workaround you can write own repository with own logic :) This is not so hard as it can be: just extend main order repository in yours and rewrite the `save()` method (remove unwanted code from it)